# Why and how does this simplification occur?

Tags: factorial

$$ \lim_{n \to infty}\frac{q!\left(nq-q\right)!n^{q}}{nq\left(nq-1\right)\left(nq-2\right)...\left(nq-q\right)!}$$
$$= \lim_{n \to infty}\frac{q!n^{q}}{n^{q}q^{q}}$$

Obviously, the $\left(nq-q\right)!$ cancels out but I am perplexed as to how the rest of the denominator becomes raised to the power of q

Comment: Double check the fraction or provide some context. You might leaving out some details (like a limit).

Comment: Yes I did in fact leave out the limit how did you know. I guess it doesn't simplify without the limit

Comment: The limit is n -> infinity

Comment: As written above, no, it doesn’t simplify much

Comment: ok what about with the limit?

Comment: Hmm I think I got it is it because as n approaches infinity the -1, -2 etc become negligible?

Comment: Oh ok thank you

Comment: I’ve understood what you mean by negligible; I guess you meant they go to zero as $n\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q!(nq-q)!n^q}{(nq(nq-1)(nq-2)\cdots(nq-q))!}$$
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q!n^q}{nq(nq-1)(nq-2)\cdots(nq-q+1)}$$
Dividing the numerator and denominator by $n^q$ then gives
$$= \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{q!}{q(q-\frac{1}{n}) (q-\frac{2}{n})\cdots(q-\frac{q-1}{n})}$$
$$=\frac{q!}{q^q}\,.$$

Comment: ok but now I don't get how the denominator becomes simply q^q in line 3 to 4

Comment: Because as $n\to\infty$ you obtain $$q(q-0) (q-0)\cdots(q-0)=q^q$$

Comment: Ahh yes I understand. Would you have an explanation for the original simplifaction though? The flaw in my reasoning is that I can't let -1,-2,-3 be negligible yet the limit has not been subbed in yet

Comment: Yes, it is only in the limit that they simplify as desired.